# Acceleration (per time step) required to reach speed

Tags: math, game-physics

I have an object that start at v0 (**0m.s^-1**) and needs to reach vf (**10m.s^-1**) in a distance of let say **25m**.

[image: Acceleration required?]

This object updates its velocity using the following equation of motion:

```
    v(n) = v(n - 1) + a * dt
```

With dt being the time interval since last frame (last computation of the velocity). And n being the current frame index.

I know that in order to reach the final speed vf and going from v0 the formula for the acceleration is:

```
a = (vf * vf - v0 * v0) / (2 * d)
```

With d being the distance (25m in our example).

But I can not use this acceleration in my equation of motion, in fact I tried but I do not get the correct speed. So I guess it's because the acceleration is not fit to be used every time step.

So do you know the correct formula to retrieve the acceleration I can use inside my equation of motion?

Comment: Are your `dt`s constant?

Comment: It should be, so let say yes 1/30 sec as an example.

Comment: Can we see the source code? I foresee a problem, if d/dt is integrated with constant velocity v(n), where as it should be `v(n) + a*dt / 2`.

Comment: Source code is too big to show, but the formula for the position is:
Vector3 pos = cur_pos + cur_vel * dt
and for the velocity:
Vector3 vel = cur_vel + acc * dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula works for straight forward leap-frog:

```js
var dt = 1.0 / 30;
var dp0 = 0, dp1 = 10;
var p0 = 0, p1 = 25;
var ddp = (dp1 * dp1 - dp0 * dp0) / (2 * (p1 - p0));
var list = document.getElementById("list");
for(var i = 0, p = p0, dp = dp0; p < p1; ++i) {
  // ddp = (dp1 * dp1 - dp * dp) / (2 * (p1 - p));
  p += dp * dt;
  dp += ddp * dt;
  var str = "";
  str += " p: " + Math.floor(p * 1000) / 1000;
  str += ", dp: " + Math.floor(dp * 1000) / 1000;
  str += ", ddp: " + Math.floor(ddp * 1000) / 1000;
  var text = document.createTextNode(str);
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  node.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, it seems to work on your snippet. Thank you for that. So that means I might be doing something wrong somewhere else. If so, my apologies.
I am doing some test.

Comment: After many tests, it seems to work with this formula. So I was doing something wrong with the update of the position.
Thank you!